# PHP : Codewars signup exercise

Tags: php

I'm trying to solve this on codewars website:

Correct this code so that the `greet` function returns the expected value.

```
class Person {
  public $name;
  public function __construct($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
  }
  public function greet($guest) {
    return 'Hello $guest, my name is $name';
  }
}
```

Where's the error?

Comment: If you can't solve atleast the signup exercise, maybe you should first look into a programming language of your choice, practice a little bit and then come back to codewars.

Answer (score 0):

[Complex (curly) syntax](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) only works with double quotes `""`

Changing it like so:

```
class Person {
  public $name;
  public function __construct($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
  }
  public function greet($guest) {
    return "Hello $guest, my name is {$this->name}";
  }

}
```

Output:

```
$x = new Person('john');
echo $x->greet('peter');

//Hello peter, my name is john
```

Comment: sorry, correct line on website is :   return 'Hello $guest, my name is $name';

Comment: I just tested it, and it passes the test.